# how to convert the result of many tables into one result

Tags: sql-server

```sql
select sum(value) as sales_value_a from tbl_a
--its result =500
select sum(value) as sales_value_b from tbl_b
--its result =600
select sum(value) as sales_value_c from tbl_c
--its result =300
```

I want result like =  tbl_a + tbl_b - tbl_c
--result =800

none of the queries i have tried are getting the right result. so  i seek the humble cooperatiion of the experienced

Comment: Could you please show queries you have tried

Comment: `UNION ALL` (in a subquery) and then aggregate?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  (select sum(value) as sales_value_a from tbl_a) +
        (select sum(value) as sales_value_b from tbl_b) + 
        (select sum(value) as sales_value_c from tbl_c) AS result
```

Comment: Not saying this is wrong, and very unlikely it'll hapen when there is no `WHERE`, however, worth noting that *if* any of subqueries return `NULL` (which would happen if there are no rows in the table), the result of the expression would also be `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned in the comments union all then aggregate

```
 with myTable(Value) as ( 
      select Value from TableA union all
      select Value from TableB union all
      select Value from TableC 
    )
     select sum(Value) from MyTable
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e63f8/9

Comment: Your answer will add all table results. But user wants to subtract the 3rd table result.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query to handle null. I have multiplied the result of table3 with (-1) as you want to subtract the result of 3rd Table.

```
SELECT SUM(value) result FROM
(
    SELECT COALESCE(sum(value), 0) value FROM tbl_a
    UNION
    SELECT COALESCE(sum(value), 0) FROM tbl_b
    UNION
    SELECT (-1)*COALESCE(sum(value), 0) FROM tbl_c
)T
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go for CROSS JOIN and apply your calculation as given below:

```sql
SELECT sum_a + sum_b -sum_c as totalsum
from
(
(select sum(value) as sales_value_a from tbl_a) as a(sum_a)
CROSS JOIN 
(select sum(value) as sales_value_b from tbl_b) as b(sum_b)
CROSS JOIN
(select sum(value) as sales_value_c from tbl_c) as c(sum_c)
)
```

> 800